# Possibility of two events to take place at the same position?

Tags: special-relativity

I started learning Special Theory of Relativity recently, so I am not well acquainted with the theory. I wanted to know if it is possible for any two events taking place at a different time and position for one frame of reference to take place at the same position for another frame of reference moving at a constant velocity (less than c) with respect to the first frame of reference.

I intuitively feel that the above case should be possible considering the effects of length contraction and time dilation. However, I am unable to get that into math (I used the equations for Lorentz transformation).

Please guide me as to where I am wrong.

My working:

Consider the two events as event A and B.

For a frame of reference, say, at rest: Event A ( t = a, x, y, z) and Event B ( t = b, X, y, z)

Now, for another frame of reference moving at velocity v, the events take place at same position so

γ (x - βca) = γ (X - βcb)

which implies |β| = |(X - x)/(a - b)|

However, I don't have any control over the limit of β. So, is my intuition wrong?

For example: Consider the events as ( t = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) and ( t = 0.33 μs, x = 200, y = 0, z = 0). Find the velocity for a different frame of reference which finds these two events at the same position. Is this possible?

Comment: When I drive from home to work, the events "I leave home" and "I arrive at work" occur at different times and positions in my home's frame, but at the same position in my car's frame.

Comment: @gamma268 I think when you approach two different events at exactly $c$, you would see the distance between the events are extremely contracted so that the events are superimposed onto each other and they occupy the same positions. WillO's answer (comment) is, however, more comprehensive.